# Getting error for Login and Logout using facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

this is my MainActivity:

```
package com.FBupdater;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    String APP_ID = getString(R.string.APP_ID);
    Facebook fb;
    ImageButton button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);

        button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        updateContentView();
    }

    private void updateContentView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(fb.isSessionValid()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.logout);
        }else{
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.login);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(fb.isSessionValid()){
            //button close our session - log out of facebook
            try {
                fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                updateContentView();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            //login to facebook
            fb.authorize(MainActivity.this, new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onFBerror", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onError", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    updateContentView(); 
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

this is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.FBupdater"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.FBupdater.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/notloggedinmessage"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/loginbtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@drawable/login"
            android:src="@drawable/login" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this the error log:

////after clicking the logout button:

```
11-28 15:22:56.824: D/AndroidRuntime(2123): Shutting down VM
11-28 15:22:56.824: W/dalvikvm(2123): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:270)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:215)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:777)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:693)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.logout(Facebook.java:652)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.timelystatusupdater.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-28 15:22:57.034: E/AndroidRuntime(2123):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 15:22:57.534: D/dalvikvm(2123): GC_CONCURRENT freed 400K, 9% free 5888K/6407K, paused 10ms+34ms
11-28 15:22:57.874: I/dalvikvm(2123): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-28 15:22:57.994: I/dalvikvm(2123): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-28 15:23:07.315: I/Process(2123): Sending signal. PID: 2123 SIG: 9
```

In the video tutorial he said it is so simple. he used facebook.logout(Context context) function. His code worked fine but mine does not.

So, what is the problem, I don't understand. Thanks in advance.

**N.B:** I am new in Android and the Facebook SDK. In fact, this is my first project in android.

I run this project for min android sdk 8, target sdk 16
and when I run it in android 2.3.3 (api 10) emulator I can logout very easily but when I run it in android 4.0.3 (api 15) emulator I can login but when I try to logout the app crashes and i get the error above.

I am following a video tutorial: [mybringback all 11 videos about facebook sdk in android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrJsLFAYITI&feature=plcp)

In the video tutorial he said it is so simple. He used `facebook.logout(Context context)` function. His code works fine but mine does not.

Comment: please can anyone give me something. i am dying here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aha, i have followed the AsyncFacebookRunner.java class and used its logout method and the problem is gone.

like

```
myAsyncFB.logout(Context, RequestListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your facebook.java there is one function...

```
public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions, int activityCode, final DialogListener listener) 
    {

        boolean singleSignOnStarted = true;

        mAuthDialogListener = listener;
        Log.d("in authorise", "authorise");
        // Prefer single sign-on, where available.
        **if (activityCode >= 0) 
        {
            Log.d("single sign", "single sign");
            singleSignOnStarted = startSingleSignOn(activity, mAppId, permissions, activityCode);
        }**/////put comment for this code...
        // Otherwise fall back to traditional dialog.
       // else
            startDialogAuth(activity, permissions);

    }
```

Comment: but in the video tutorial he done the same coding as i type in my question. so, if his app run fine then my app should also run fine. but it doesn't. so what is the problem. And i don't understand about your solution, because i am new in android and facebook sdk. so what is the problem and what should i do ? @Mehelu1000

Answer (score 0):

The version of the Facebook SDK you are using is rather old (yes, I know it's the latest published). As such, some of the things it does internally are intended to work on Froyo (2.2), and do not account for changes that ICS (4.0) introduced.

One such change in ICS is that strict mode for apps is turned on by default. Strict mode applies bunch of checks at run time to the app behavior intended to ensure best practices and smooth user experience. One such check is whether the app is performing network requests on the main thread. This is an important check, as network requests can block for a long time, during which the UI (which is rendered on the main thread) will be unresponsive to the user.

The error you see on ICS is exactly that - the strict check for netwrok request on the main thread is failing in the Facebook `logout()` method. Hence the exception `NetworkOnMainThread`.

To avoid this, in your `onClickListener` you can use `AsyncTask` with simple `Runnable` (using the static [`AsyncTask.execute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method) to initiate the logout on another thread. Something like this (code written in browser, so check for sanity):

```
    // ... cut ...
    if(fb.isSessionValid()){
        //button close our session - log out of facebook
        try {
            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                    // You can also use MainActivity.this instead of getApplicationContext()
                }
            });
            updateContentView();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // ... cut ...
```

This is the simple version of course, just to unblock you. If you want your UI to be exactly synchronized with when the logout finished, you'll have to write a bit more code.

Comment: i write down the code you have described. but eclipse said that:

 " Multiple markers at this line
  -Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method                                         exicute(Object...) from the type AsyncTask
  -AsyncTask is raw type. References to generic type AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> should be parameterized
  -Type safety: The method execut(Object...) belongs to the raw type AsyncTask. References to generic type AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> should be parameterized " 

so, what should i do now? @Franci Penov

Comment: Make sure you're using API level 11 (since the static execute method was added then). If you want to support older API levels, then you'll need to create your own AsyncTask subclass.

Comment: Ah, the static `execute(Runnable)` method was added in API 11. Since you are targeting min API 8, you will have to write slightly different code, with your own subclass of the `AsyncTask` and call `logout` in the `doInBackground` override.

Comment: aha, i have followed the AsyncFacebookRunner.java class and used its logout method and the problem is gone. but now i am facing a new problem. can you please help me. here is the link: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636638/why-is-my-facebook-session-still-valid-after-i-am-logged-out) @FranciPenov

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook API change every days, it's a crap, but you could check this proyect and i think it will be perfect for you

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Comment: This is more suited as a comment on the OP, as even though it does point to the right place (the official Facebook for Android SDK), it does not address the problem.